# Can there be multiple font-sizes within one <input>'s value

Tags: html, input, font-size

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
<input value="<span style='font-size:10px'>small text</span>
       <span style='font-size:20px'>BIG TEXT</span>" 
       type="text" />
```

This code doesn't work. But can I mimic this?

Comment: You can if you use CSS selectors to your advantage, but not if you try to embed markup within the element `value` attribute itself.

Comment: If the user modifies the text, how is it supposed to know how to render it?

Comment: Good point, pyrospade, but for my purposes, I would only need different font sizes initially. But that is a great point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing styles within a `textbox` is not possible with pure HTML and CSS. What you'll need to look for is a third-party control for `richtextbox`.  Just Google your platform ([PHP](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&redir_esc=&client=ms-android-att-us&source=android-browser-type&v=133247963&qsubts=1343616389024&action=devloc&q=php+richtextbox&v=133247963) or [ASP.NET](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=ms-android-att-us&source=android-browser-type&v=133247963&q=asp.net+richtextbox&oq=asp.net+richtextbox&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i7j0i30j0i7i30l3.56871.60600.0.62112.10.10.0.0.0.0.170.1187.1j8.9.0...0.0...1ac.mVjCaJ5sIvI&mvs=0)) to find one to your liking.